# Does select_related (prefetch_related) improve performance for query filter parameters

Tags: python, sql, django

Imagine I have the following setup in a Django model

```
class Sale(Model):
     customer = ForeignKey(Customer)  #person who purchased something
     date = ForeignKey(Date) #date the sale was made
```

Now I want to look at all the sales on a particular day and examine those customers.  I know that doing a `prefetch_related` or `select_related` with `Customer` on the filter can help for doing something like the following

```
query = Sale.objects.filter(date=some_date).prefetch_related('customer')
for sale in query:
    #do something with customer
```

This would prevent a bunch of single SQL lookups on customer.

But does adding `Date` to the `prefetch` help the SQL query as well if I'm not using `Date` outside the query call?

Comment: Only further filtering of the results affects query handling, so in your case no the filtering does not affect the proper operation of prefetch_related

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it would help the performance. It would only be needed if you are accessing `sale.date`  inside the loop.

Also I believe that select_related is the right function to use in your case.

A good way to monitor this is to count the number of queries that happen during a request (before/after using selected_related). The [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) can show you the number of queries that the django orm made when loading a page.

Answer (score 0):

`prefetch related` allow to use a few relation arguments, so you can try to modified your query like this:

```
query = Sale.objects.filter(date=some_date).prefetch_related('customer', 'date')
```